# Passar parametro janela modal bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Boa tarde pessoal, tenho um problema que deve ser bobo, mas não estou conseguindo resolver.

Tenho uma lista de pessoas... nessa lista tenho um botão.
Ao passar o mouse sobre o botão, aparece o ID correto da pessoa.

Porém quando clico no botão, abre o modal, e o campo ID apresenta um numero diferente.

```
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="<c:url value="upload?cod=${pessoa.cod}"/>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testes">Upload Doc</a>
```

E aqui meu modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="testes" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <%@include file="formUpload.jsp" %>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

E por fim meu "formulário":

```
<form name="formUpload"  id="formUpload" action="<c:url value="/pessoa/uploadDoc"/>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="pessoa.cod" id="pessoaCod" class="id" value="${pessoa.cod}">
```

Estou confusa com isso.

Esse campo não mostra o id correto.

Comment: Você pode tentar colocar um onclick no link, chamando uma função javascript que popule os campos do modal em tempo de execução.

Comment: O comportamento do Id é sempre o mesmo? Por exemplo, independente do id certo, ele sempre passa o id 0 para o modal? Ou ele tem comportamento diferente?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer via javascript populando os campos do modal ao clicar. Segue exemplo

Link

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="setaDadosModal('valor1')">
    <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>Abrir modal
</a>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function setaDadosModal(valor) {
    document.getElementById('campo').value = valor;
}
</script>
```

Modal

```
<div id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form id="modalExemplo" method="post" action="">
                        <input type="text" name="campo" id="campo">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado. :)

Comment: É o que o Paulo comentou, precisa alterar o id pelo javascript antes de mostrar o modal